# Moto G5S Plus don't connect do Android Studio/Windows10 PRO

Tags: android, adb, driver, motorola

I'm working on a Launcher who should run into a old device (Moto G5S Plus). It's been designed to my mother in law who has seriously sight problems.  But I don't need help with her, ofcourse!

I can't find a viable ADB driver to connec the **Moto G5S Plus** into my **Windows 10 PRO 64 bits** (*compilation 19042.8xx*).  I had searched into dozens of sites but all them nothing.

- Mobile: **Moto G5S Plus** (*Developer mode activated*)
- Desktop: **Windows 10 PRO 64 bits** (compile 19042.8xx)
- Android Studio: **v4.0.2**

I'm intending to work all the weekend to finish de application and test it. *So if anybody could save me soul in this one, I'll apreciate*!

**There's anybody with the same issue who managed to work it out?**

Thank's for any tip!

- [About the device screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGv09.png)
- [My Android Studio info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr2fI.png)